# Search for a certain "td class" and replace it

Tags: html, css

so I have this code:

```
<td class="side userlink">
    <a href="/forums/profile/2394-thethiny/">
        <span style="color: #97ACEF;" title="thethiny (2394) [Normal user]">thethiny</span>
    </a>
</td>
```

I need a CSS code that finds the above code and replaces the color #97ACEF with the color #FFFFFF.

I tried putting this under the above code so hopefully it would replace it, but it didn't :

```
<style>
    <td class="side userlink">
        <a href="/forums/profile/2394-thethiny/">
            <span style="color: #FFFFFF;" title="thethiny (2394) [Normal user]">thethiny</span>
        </a>
    </td>
</style>
```

I even tried adding `body` after `<style>` and still didn't work.

I want the color to be replaced only under `td class side userlink` and not in the whole page.

I also tried this:

```
."side userlink":after {
    content:"<a href="/forums/profile/2394-thethiny/"><span style="color: #FFFFFF;" title="thethiny (2394)[Normal user]">thethiny</span></a>";
}
```

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: The things you're trying aren't even valid.

Comment: then can you point me on how to do them?

Comment: Do you want the color to ALWAYS be #ffffff?  Or just certain times?  Like on hover?

Comment: The html tag style="" takes precedence over all other CSS attributes. It's best to remove the style="color: #FFFFFF" from all your spans and assign them classes. Then manipulate the spans accordingly. Although, Javascript can over-ride it as @Sam mentioned below.

Comment: @Nick here's the thing:
there's this page http://rvlution.net/forums/profile/2394/
we're allowed to put HTML/CSS elements into your pages, there's an element called "td class", it has the Color value under it, (the right chat box). I just want to replace the color assigned to "thethiny" to #FFFFFF on the chat box only ( td class="side userlink")
thanks

Comment: In that case, if you cannot update the <span>'s then what you are asking for is impossible.

Comment: You can take a look at Javascript...

Comment: @Rich this user http://rvlution.net/forums/profile/28/ has done that, he replaced it with yellow.

Comment: @user3025371 Where did he do that? Where can I find that?

Comment: I've answered below.  If you have somewhere you're able to put HTML/CSS, that will work fine

Comment: @user3025371 Isn't there some BBcode or something? It's sometimes used by fora which allows you to create a small amount of layout customizations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Okay... So if you can add HTML/CSS somewhere.  This will work for you

```
<style>
.userlink span {
color: #ffffff!important;
}
</style>
```

http://gyazo.com/d4182ccd03288312f98640dc93b1d9cc

**Update**

Add this -

```
<style>
    .cell2 span {
    color: #ff00eb!important;
    }
</style>
```

I'm not sure what color you actually want.  So change #ff00eb to the hex color you need.

**More Updates**

This should work for you :)

```
<style>
.usercomments tr td:nth-child(2n-1) a[href="/forums/profile/2394-thethiny/"] :not(.pagelink) {
color: #ff00eb!important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: What section of the site do you add your code to?  I've made a test account

Comment: Here - It's worked for me?
http://rvlution.net/forums/profile/3086/

Edit My Profile > Personal > Put it in the top of your Bio

Comment: you go to your profile on the right, then Edit profile.

Comment: go to personal, the BIO is where you can add all <style> commands. You can also add them to <Post Layout>

Comment: The default theme is white.
Look, try adding a comment on your chat box on your profile, then under the BIO or Post LAyout, try adding a script that changes your color from purple or blue to white. see if it works

Comment: Updated my original post.  Check the profile.  I've changed that text to pink.  They're classed differently so it doesn't change everything.  http://rvlution.net/forums/profile/3086/

Comment: thank you but, this changes all of the users together, isn't there a way to make it change only 1 user? which is thethiny?

Thanks for your help though :D

Comment: Unfortunately not.  You'd need jQuery for that as the chat items aren't individually classed per user.  Just done a quick test and it wouldn't let me use jQuery in the Bio sorry!  Maybe you could email support to see if they can add custom user classes.  Wouldn't be too hard :)  Hopefully that helped though!

Comment: I appreciate your help. take a look at this user, he did it:

Comment: http://rvlution.net/forums/profile/28-ganjagrinda/
you can look at the source of the page.
sorry for the trouble :S

Comment: just a tip, I removed "tr td:nth-child(2n-1)" and it still worked.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use CSS styles to replace HTML elements. If an HTML element has a style attribute, you cannot override it with a style sheet. You have two options either replace the HTML which I gather you cannot or you can use Javascript to manipulate these HTML Elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after changing the color at any time (why would you want to do that at the beginning without editing the actual code? ), you can use simple javascript code. First give the span an id:

```
<td class="side userlink">
  <a href="/forums/profile/2394-thethiny/">
    <span id="thinySpan" style="color: #97ACEF;" title="thethiny (2394) [Normal user]">thethiny</span>
  </a>
</td>
```

Then manipulate the font color with javascript:

```
function changeColor(){
document.getElementById('thinySpan').style.color = '#FFFFFF';
}
```

Comment: I can't use Javascript, only HTML and CSS between <style> </style>

Comment: Is this something about homework or are you restricted by lack of knowledge? Cause otherwise, why not use a <script> tag? You can put js in there. If you tell us when and for what reason you want to change the color, we can help you out much better.

Comment: we have a field of text where we're only allowed to "add" <Style> elements only. we cannot replace or remove.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thats weird, but ok.

Replace your code for the following:

HTML:

```
<td class="side userlink">
   <a href="/forums/profile/2394-thethiny/" title="thethiny (2394) [Normal user]">thethiny</a>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
td a{
    color: #97ACEF;
}

.side.userlink a{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Resulting HTML + CSS

```
<style>
td a{
    color: #97ACEF;
}

.side.userlink a{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>

<td class="side userlink">
    <a href="/forums/profile/2394-thethiny/" title="thethiny (2394) [Normal user]">thethiny</a>
</td>
```

This will set all the anchors as `#97ACEF`, and will only put `#FFFFFF` on what has both `.side` and `.userlink` classes.

*Ps: Pay attention to the semantics, you had a unecessary `span` inside the `a`, and take a look at the [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), you can select pretty much anything you want with it.*